# The difference between modeling hierarchies in normalized and dimensional data modeling

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I have trouble understanding the differences between modeling hierarchies in normalized and dimensional data modeling? I will very much appreciate your time and answers.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are many approaches to model hierarchies in the relational databses.

Comment: I need to understand it in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normalized schema for a transactional database, a hierarchy might look like this:

```
create table geopolitical_area (
  id bigint primary key,
  type text not null,
  name text not null,
  code char(2),
  parent_id bigint null references geopolitical_area(id)  
);

insert into geopolitical_area values
(1, 'Country', 'Canada', 'CA', null),
(2, 'Region', 'British Columbia', 'BC', 1);
```

Note the foreign key to the same table.

In a dimensional schema for a data warehouse, a hierarchy might look like this:

```
create table dim_customer (
  id bigint,
  name text,
  country_name text,
  country_code char(2),
  region_name text,
  region_code char(2) ...
);

insert into dim_customer values
(666, 'Neil McGuigan', 'Canada', 'CA', 'British Columbia', 'BC' ...);
```

Notice that the hierarchy has been flattened.

Often, you analyze a data warehouse using OLAP, where you would tell your OLAP server about the country > region hiearchy.

For example, in Mondrian OLAP server, a hierarchy might look like this:

```
<Dimension name="location">
  <Hierarchy>
    <Table name="dim_customer" />
    <Level name="Country" column="country_code" nameColumn="country_name" />
    <Level name="Region" column="region_code" nameColumn="region_name" />
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

Comment: A slowly changing hierachical dimension may introduce another level of complexity to the dimensional model.